# Distribution of $\max_i \bar{X}-X_i$

Tags: joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, conditional-independence

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables from the standard normal distribution and let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be their sample mean.

I'm interested in the distribution of the $Y_i = \bar{X}-X_i$. Specifically, assuming that there exists a $p(\varepsilon)$ such that for any $i$
$$\mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) \le p(\varepsilon),$$
I'm trying to bound $\mathbb{P}(\max_i|Y_i|\le\varepsilon)$ as a function of $p(\epsilon)$ and $n$.
If the $Y_i$ were independent, we could readily write
$$\mathbb{P}(\max_i|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) \le p(\varepsilon)^n.$$
Unfortunately, the $Y_i$ are not independent. I've tried another approach and I'm wondering whether it is correct.

**Step 1.**
The $Y_i$  are jointly normally distributed and they are all independent from $\bar{X}$.

**Step 2.**
Therefore, the conditional probability distribution of $Y_i$ given $\bar{X}$ is equal to its unconditional distribution, and so $\mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon \mid \bar{X}=\bar{x})$.

**Step 3.**
When $\bar{X}=\bar{x}$ is fixed, $Y_i = \bar{X} - X_i = \bar{x} - X_i$ and since the $X_i$ are independent, the $Y_i$ are all mutually conditionally independent given $\bar{X}$.
Therefore,
$$\mathbb{P}(\max_i|Y_i|\le\varepsilon \mid \bar{X}=\bar{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon \mid \bar{X}=\bar{x}).$$

It seems to me that by combining Steps 1-3 we can conclude
$$\mathbb{P}(\max_i|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\max_i|Y_i|\le\varepsilon \mid \bar{X}=\bar{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon \mid\bar{X}=\bar{x})= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|Y_i|\le\varepsilon) \le p(\varepsilon)^n.$$

I find this result "too good to be true" since this is what we would get if the $Y_i$ were independent. Could someone confirm whether the line of reasoning above is correct or, if not, point out where the error lies?

Comment: For anyone curious about the context, this problem arises in the field of stochastic numerical validation of floating-point computations. Modelling rounding errors as random variables, if we repeat a given computation $n$ times and compare the $n$ results $X_i$ to their sample mean, we can estimate the accuracy of the computation as a function of $\max_i |\bar{X}-X_i|$.

Comment: Please edit your question title to better match the question. You could derive the joint distribution of $Y$ directly.

Comment: A hint, $Y=AX$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and thus $Y$ has an n-variate normal distribution.

Comment: Possibly the distribution of $\max(|x_i-\bar{x}|)$ can be related to a [range distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)). It's not an easy thing to work with.

Comment: I've added $max_i$ in the title, which is indeed a crucial detail of my question (sorry for the confusion).
@utobi: this should clarify it's not the $Y_i$ (which are indeed multivariate normal) I'm interested in, but the $\max_i Y_i$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: I agree, not easy... I've moved away from $\max_i Y_i$ in favor of $\sum Y_i^2$, which is much nicer ($\chi^2_{n-1}$ by Cochran's theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Step 3.**
> When $\bar{X}=\bar{x}$ is fixed, $Y_i = \bar{X} - X_i = \bar{x} - X_i$ and since the $X_i$ are independent

The $X_i$ are not independent when you condition on $\bar{X}$.

(and also when you consider to not condition on $\bar{X}$, the $X_i$ are not independent from $\bar{X}$ so the left hand side in  $Y_i = \bar{X} - X_i$ does not need to be independent if the $X_i$ are independent)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!